# How to deal with multiple active cells when replacing text

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to modify the text of my cells on the fly. 
ex: "n", "N" or "new" ---> "New"

I've got it working, however I'm having issues when I select multiple cells to delete the text.

Can someone help identify how I could accomplish this goal and still be able to modify multiple excel cell values (deleting is my only concern unless you can think of other limitations my code may cause).

--Just to clarify, my code will change the text the way I want it to, however, when I select multiple cells and press the delete key (to delete the cells' values) I get a type mismatch for Range(Target.Address).Value

Thanks everyone for your time,
Al

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim OriginalText As String
    Dim CorrectedText As String
        OriginalText = Range(Target.Address).Value
        If OriginalText = "r" Or OriginalText = "R" Or OriginalText = "replace" Then
           CorrectedText = "Replace"
           Range(Target.Address).Value = CorrectedText
        ElseIf OriginalText = "a" Or OriginalText = "A" Or OriginalText = "acceptable" Then
            CorrectedText = "Acceptable"
           Range(Target.Address).Value = CorrectedText
        ElseIf OriginalText = "n" Or OriginalText = "N" Or OriginalText = "new" Then
            CorrectedText = "New"
           Range(Target.Address).Value = CorrectedText
        End If

End Sub
```

Update:
I can't tell you how much I appreciate everyone's generosity! Thank you for your help. I hope this can assist others in need as well.
Cheers, Al

Comment: put `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` at the top.

Comment: Also needs `Application.EnableEvents = False` before you update the sheet, or you'll again trigger the event needlessly.  Set back to `True` when done.

Answer (score 0):

Use Areas:

```
Dim area,cell as range
For each area in target.areas
    For each cell in area.cells
        OriginalText = cell.value
    next
next
```

Comment: I would go with `for each cell in target` since why create a new range (or area) when one is already created, although I don't think OP wants to loop through cells when multiple ones are selected.

Comment: I didn't actually realise it was `Worksheet_Change` so yes indeed. Target it is

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c As Range, newText As String, v

    'exit if too many cells (eg whole column)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1000 Then Exit Sub

    For Each c In Target.Cells
        v = c.Value
        Select Case v
            Case "r", "R", "replace": newText = "Replace"
            Case "a", "A", "acceptable": newText = "Acceptable"
            Case "n", "N", "new": newText = "New"
            Case Else: newText = v
        End Select
        If newText <> v Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                c.Value = newText
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```